# Express not seving static images from view/subfolders

Tags: node.js, express

I have a problem where my static images work perfectly when linked from `/views` folder and from `/views/partials` folder, but when I put a subfolder between `/views/courses/partials` my image stops working.

I am using

```
app.use(express.static(__dirname + "/public"));
```

My file structure:

```
> app
    - app.js
    > public
        > assets
            > images
                > icons
                    - link.png
    > views
        - landing.ejs
        > partials 
            - header.ejs 
        > courses
            - courses.ejs (images is working when linked from here)
            > partials
                - lectures.ejs //This file is a partial of courses.ejs (images not working when linked from here)
```

The path I use is `/assets/images/icons/link.png`

Here is my `app.js` if needed

```
//REQUIREMENTS - requiering files for App.js
var express = require("express"),
    app = express(),
    passport = require("passport"),
    bodyParser = require("body-parser"),
    mongoose = require("mongoose"),
    flash = require("connect-flash"),
    passportSetup = require("./config/passport"),
    methodOverride = require("method-override"),
    User = require("./models/user"),
    Course = require("./models/course"),
    middleware = require("./middleware"),
    path = require("path");

//REQUIERING ROUTES - requiering routes files
var indexRoutes = require("./routes/index");
var authRoutes = require("./routes/auth");
var adminRoutes = require("./routes/admin");
var messageRoutes = require("./routes/message");
var courseRoutes = require("./routes/courses");

// DATABASE CONNECTION - conecting to mongoDB using enviroment variables
var dbUrl = "mongodb://localhost/example" || process.env.DATABASEURL;
mongoose.connect(dbUrl);

//METHOD OVERRIDE - override http method
app.use(methodOverride("_method"));

//FLASH MESSAGES - use flash messages
app.use(flash());

//BODY PARSER - using bodyparser to easily retrieve http info
app.use(bodyParser.urlencoded({extended: true}));

//STATIC DIRECTORIES - use static directories for clientside linking
app.use(express.static(__dirname + "/public"));
^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^

//VIEW ENGINE - default view engine
app.set("view engine", "ejs");

//PASSPORT CONFIGURATION - setting express session secret
app.use(require("express-session")({
    secret: "************************",
    resave: false,
    saveUninitialized: false
}));
app.use(passport.initialize());
app.use(passport.session());

//CURRENT USER - sending current user to every route
app.use(function(req, res, next){
    res.locals.currentUser = req.user;
    next();
});

//ROUTES - all routes are used here
app.use(authRoutes);
app.use(adminRoutes);
app.use(messageRoutes);
app.use(courseRoutes);
app.use(indexRoutes);

//LISTENING PORT - port to listen to
var port = 4000 || process.env.PORT;

//LISTEN - listen on chosen port
app.listen(port, process.env.IP,function(){
    //Startup message
    console.log("Server has started!");
});
```

And here is my `lectures.ejs` file:

```
<div id="lectures-content" class="page-section--small">
    <div class="wrapper--no-padding course-lectures">
        <div class="course-lectures__lecture flex">
            <div class="course-lectures__left">
                <div class="text-area">
                    <div class="text-area__smallheading">Lecture 1</div>
                    <div class="text-area__text text-area__text--small">This is the first lecture</div>
                </div>
            </div>
            <div class="course-lectures__right flex">
                <div class="course-lectures__number">Lecture: 1</div>
                <div class="course-lectures__arrow">
                    <img class="course-lectures__image" src="/assets/images/icons/link.jpg" alt="">
^                   ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^
                </div>
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>
</div>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think there's a mismatch in the filetype of you picture:
`link.jpg != link.png`

Comment: Wow, I stared at that for several hours. I am ashamed :(

Answer (score 0):

Try this: It may help you

```
app.use(express.static('./public'));
```

Make sure that your app.js must be in the same directory,

Comment: I tried, but it didn't work. My app.js is in the app directory. (added it into my question now)